# Asymptote fill area inside implicit curve

Tags: asymptote, fill

I use Asymptote to make the graphics. I have a curve defined as contour of a surface. I want to fill by color the area inside curve. The problem is that contour returns a guide structure in Asymptote, and this is not accepted to to buildcycle command. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ? Thanks. This is the code I use and which produce the curve:

```
import graph3;
import contour;

size(6cm,0);

real f(real x, real y) { return (1+x+x^2/2-y^2/2)^2 + (y+y*x)^2-1; }
guide[][] thegraphs = contour(f, a=(-2,-2), b=(2,2), new real[] {0});
/* The next line draws the first (and
only) entry in thegraphs. This entry
is itself an array, since it
represents a disconnected path. */
draw(thegraphs,linewidth(2.0));

xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks,above=true);
yaxis("$y$",LeftRight,RightTicks,above=true);
```

Comment: Replacing `graph3` by `graph`, `draw(thegraphs,linewidth(2.0));` by such as `filldraw(thegraphs[0],red+opacity(.6));`

Comment: Thank you, It's work fine!